# PHP / PDO echo data from database into a table

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have been searching for a while now and I've been trying to put my data from my database into my html table. How do I achieve this? Here is my code.

CONFIG.PHP

```
<?php
try {
    $db = new PDO("mysql:host=127.0.0.1;dbname=boekingdb", "root", "");
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print($e->getMessage());
}
```

PHP CODE:

```
<?php
$getUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$getUser->execute();
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();
foreach ($users as $user) {
  echo $user['username'];
  echo $user['password'];
} ?>
```

Comment: `<?php echo $row['username'] ?>`

Comment: Why are you escaping the brackets - `{$row\['username'\]}`?

Comment: the html is useless, unless you embed it inside your foreach loop, and the `\[` stuff is pointless as well... you're not echoing the php in the html anyways, you're basically doing "here's a row variable" and php's going " fine, whatever".

Comment: Sorry for the confusion guys, I added the html but that wasn't necessary. My question is how do I  make a table and add multiple usernames and passwords to it?

Comment: Please use PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html) to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).

Comment: `var_dump($users);` to see if the array is, in fact, populated. It will not be in this case because you have not included CONFIG.PHP in your second script. No connection = no results. Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening `<?php` tag `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);`

Answer (score 0):

Ok so I have figured it out

```
<?php
$getUser = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users");
$getUser->execute();
$users = $getUsers->fetchAll();

<table>
    <tr>
      <th>Username</th>
      <th>Password</th>
    </tr>
<?php foreach ($users as $user) { ?>
<tr>
   <td><?php echo $users['username'] ?></td>
   <td><?php echo $users['password'] ?></td>
</tr>
<?php } ?>
</table>
```

It now echo's every username and password inside the table. even if I add new ones in the database I just hit refresh and they are added.

Sorry for writing my question in a confusing way.

Comment: There is no way this works. `$users` != `$user` in your foreach loop and you still have no connection. You must not be sharing the entire picture with us.

Answer (score 0):

So i've edited the names and stuff to the things I need for my project but it is still pretty much the same. I've also made a function of the select statement and put that in an external file. here are some screenshots.

[This is the functions.php file where I require the config.php file (Config.php is where my connection is written)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O0jaE.png)

[This is the index.php where I include the functions.php file and also make the for each loop "I've moved the for each loop down into the table for it to work"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m7UgU.png)